# Windows 8 Bind Image URL to Image control with network credential?

Tags: image, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, networkcredentials

I am having a image url that has network credential to pass. This I want to bind on XAML for Windows 8 App. If I directly bind as below it doesn't show any image because it needs network credential. I have list of images which I need to bind one after the other at certain time interval like banner.

```
<image source={binding imgURL} />
```

How can I download and directly bind image with network credentail and rotate it like banner?

Comment: This sounds like two questions.  You're more likely to get answers if you split it out into two.

Comment: couldn't you just use HttpClient (HttpWebRequest, etc.) to download the images into a collection of BitmapImage and then bind from there